# REQUEST: Appending {number} to end of file upon transfer

Tags: sed, terminal, command, file-copy

I have thousands of directories, within each directory is a subdirectory with a file called `file.jpg`. Since each subdirectory has a file called `file.jpg` I cannot transfer all those files into the same folder or they just overwrite each other until the last (one) `file.jpg` remains.

Instead, I want to paste some commands into terminal to do the following:

1. Append a `{number}` to each `file.jpg` upon copying to a 'review' folder. Note: there could be thousands of files so there should be no limit to where it stops. The last file could be `file34634657.jpg` for example.

Side question: will there be any way to trace back the copied `file{number}.jpg` to its original directory/subdirectory? These `file.jpg` are within directories that contain other subdirectories and files that may need to be reviewed.

Comment: You could always trace back its original directory by file size and hash value. If you need a mapping, you could save the new filename and original path in a text file.

Comment: There are lots of options. Hard link or symbolic link would allow you to track a file back to its original location. Modifying the file name to include an approximation to the source path as had been mentioned already)

Comment: Why did my post get downvoted?

Comment: To trace back directories, I'd store all dir-Indexes (number of occurring) in a separate file and add the index number to the filename like `file_dirNbr_n.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding numbers is not mandatory requirement you can put paths in your file names.
That way you will solve both of your "issues" (overwritting files and not being able to trace back).

```
for ef in $(find * -name file.jpg); do cp $ef /path/to/dest_dir/$(echo $ef | sed 's,/,--,g'); done
```

-`find *` - `*`to get rid of `./` at the beginning of files,
-`$(echo $ef | sed 's,/,--,g')` - use sed to change `/` to `--` (with this you will be able to trace back or you can use something more specific instead `--`).

Edit (due to OP comment below):
If your directories contain blank/white spaces change your IFS (Internal Field Separator).
If you want, you can backup your current one and restore it at the end of your command.

```
old_IFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for ef in $(find * -name file.jpg); do cp $ef dest_dir/$(echo $ef | sed 's,/,--,g;s/ /_/g'); done; IFS=$old_IFS
```

- `old_IFS=$IFS` - backup your current IFS (which is, by default, `space`, `tab` and `newline`),
- `IFS=$'\n'` - set IFS to be `newline` (just `newline`) to avoid word splitting by `space`,
- `IFS=$old_IFS` - restore IFS back to its default value.

Of course you can remove second sed script `s/ /_/g` and just leave one (first one) if you want your files (at the destination location) include spaces from directories.

Comment: EDIT: This worked except it did not copy all of the file.jpg. There are 650 files within several subdirectories of one directory. It copied only 50 out of 650. Any idea why? 

UPDATE: I see that it is trying to access the files but there is a space within the directory file name. Within terminal it breaks at the space and looks at it as 2 directories. I guess I would need to add to this command to remove the space from the directories only or escape the space ( \ ? ) somehow. Can you modify the command to include this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @linuxuser24569, see my updated answer. In short you shoud change IFS. For more info on IFS you can use man page of bash: `man bash` and search for `IFS`, `Word Splitting` and `QUOTING`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! If I may ask a *bonus question* on this one. Is it possible to change the file type to 'any extension' and specify a keyword that may be within the file name? Is it as easy as changing from: (find * -name file.jpg) to: (find * -name keyword.*) ? --- I am putting an asterisk on either side of "keyword" but it turning the text italic. So please look at that word as having an asterisk on either side of it.

Comment: Yes, you can change it that way, but add `-type f` and quote `"*keyword.*"`. The whole command: `old_IFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for ef in $(find * -type f -name "*keyword.*"); do cp $ef dest_dir/$(echo $ef | sed 's,/,--,g;s/ /_/g'); done; IFS=$old_IFS`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. It is very appreciated.

Comment: @linuxuser24569, you are welcome. Does everything work as you expect? All files being copied, no errors?

Comment: Yes, it all works good. I have not tried the keyword method yet. We'll see if I ever need to use it that way. Thanks for everything.